# Is there any way to set timeout at child_process spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

is there any way to set timeout option at child_process spawn?

Here is my code. But I think it doesn't work....
When I remove this : `, { timeout: 100 * 60 }` , it works.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

function spawnPython() {
  const job2 = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '36 17 * * *',
    onTick() {
      const smartstoreReview = spawn(
        'python3', ['smartstore_review.py'], { timeout: 100 * 60 }
      )
.
.
.
```

Comment: How long did you intend the timeout to be?

Comment: @LoganDevine I think it will be start in 6000 ms (6 sec)

Comment: Started **in**? Timeout sets how **long** it can run. To spawn it in 6 seconds wrap it in a setTimeout().

Comment: @LoganDevine wow I misunderstood about timeout.. thank you!

Comment: Please mark mine as an answer if it helped.

Comment: @LoganDevine I did. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple problem from comments:

They expected `timeout` to set "run in 6 seconds", not "run for 6 seconds" (that's timeout)